# How will you make the url dynamic using the food variable?

Tags: javascript, rest

**How will you make the URL dynamic using the food variable?**

const url = `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s={food}`

[image]

Comment: What you're looking for is called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 0):

I cant put this as a comment, but could you maybe try going into a little more detail about your question please?

if this is what i think it is however, i would do something like this

```js
const url = `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${food}`
```

Comment: You can actually put it as a comment if you use the tilde ` symbol before and after.
`const url = `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${food}``